# Maven: how to make things different in a parent while all children behave otherwise?

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module Maven project (one level deep only). I like not to have to repeat the same things in all child projects, but how can I still do it (avoir repeating) when the parent project itself needs a different setting ?

The example I’m facing is when trying to produce a common folder for all artifacts and dependencies (but I can imagine other equivalent situations):

```
<properties>
    <__.build.folder>../last_build</__.build.folder>
</properties>
```

Of course, this will lead to a situation where I have two *last_build* folder, one common to all child projects, one in the upper level folder.

How can I avoid that without having to duplicate the same setting in every child pom.xml ?

Can I use profiles ?
I don’t know, I’m new to Maven.

Thanks

*Edit* :
In this example, *last_build* is a subfolder of the folder containing the parent pom.xml. The child projects are all in other subfolders, from which *last_build* has to be addressed as "../last_build" - but not in the parent pom.xml !

```
|
*--rootFolder
|      |
|      *--last_build // aggregation folder
|      |      
|      *--subProject1 
|      |      |
|      |      *--pom.xml (../last_build)
|      |
|      *--subProject2 
|      |      |
|      |      *--pom.xml (../last_build)
|      |
|      *--subProject3 
|      |      |
|      |      *--pom.xml (../last_build)
|      |      
|      *--pom.xml (last_build) // different here for the parent project
```

Comment: Why does the parent project need a different folder?

Comment: What is the purpose of an information about the last_build in your pom or properties?

Comment: common build folder -- don't do that, you don't need it

Comment: Top level project shouldn't exist -- it should just have the pom and the directories for the modules.

Comment: It’s not a common build folder, it’s a common folder improperly called “last_build” (legacy), where all artifacts and dependencies are to be gathered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're proceeding down a very useful path and I think that you may be confused about a few things.

First, at the highest level, your root or parent pom, there should be no project, no code, no resources, and no artifact, so there should also be no output or need for an output directory. All you should have at the highest level is the parent pom and subdirectories containing modules.

The next problem is that you think you need a common build folder. I am hard pushed to imagine a rational scenario where that would be necessary. The artifacts one typically builds in maven are self-contained jars/wars -- one per module, and these are cached in the local repo whenever you build through the `install` lifecycle. They can be used in situ from there.

Comment: Thanks, but you stick too closeley to what was just an example of my original question. The original question is “how to define some property which will be applied in all sub-poms or child-poms but not in the parent pom”.

Comment: I chose this “last_build” example because it’s a real case here, all artifacts and dependencies have to be gathered in one folder, which is not a build folder - the name is legacy. But this example was not the purpose of the original question...

Comment: But I like the first part of your aswer. My projects follow that pattern except for one thing : I specify some dependencies in the root pom because I expect these dependencies to be in every sub-pom (junit in the test phase for example). When I run the dependencies plugin to copy all dependencies in that “last_build” folder, these dependencies are copied to an upper “last_build” folder, which is wrong. I think I should filter out test dependencies.